# Python / Django - is there an assertion similar to Rails' assert_difference?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Rails has an assertion that tests for the the difference of a value after executing a block.  From [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_difference):

```
assert_difference 'Article.count', 1 do
  post :create, article: {...}
end
```

This assertion will execute the post creation command, and test that the `Article.count` has incremented by 1 after executing the block.

Is there a similar assertion in Python or Django?  If not, is the most efficient implementation just to store the number, then get it again afterwards?

Comment: Maybe `Tests`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/

Comment: It is not one of the assertions that comes included in Django or Python, I believe: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#assertions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Explicit is better than Implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

This does essentially the same thing.

```
pre_count = Article.objects.count()

# Your Logic

post_count = Article.objects.count()

self.assertEqual(post_count-pre_count, 1)
```

**OR**, for that extra ruby flavoring,

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from contextlib import contextmanager

def ExtendedTestCase(TestCase):

    @method_decorator(context_manager)
    def assertDifference(self, func, diff, message=None):
        " A Context Manager that performs an assert. "
        old_value = func()
        yield # `with` statement runs here. Roughly equivalent to ruby's blocks
        new_value = func()
        self.assertEqual(new_value-old_value, diff, message)

def ArticleTestCase(ExtendedTestCase):

    def test_article_creation(self):
        " Test that new articles can be created "
        with self.assertDifference(Article.count, 1):
             self.client.post("/article/new/", {
                 "title": "My First Django Article",
                 "content": "Boring Technical Content",
             })
```